# JRuby Warbler - How to compile gems also

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, jruby, warbler

I know `warble compiled`, but this command compiles only the source of a project.
I want that warbler compiles gems together. How to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create 'config' folder in your project folder
2. Run `warble config`, and 'config/warble.rb' is created
3. Edit the warble.rb file -- `config.compile_gems = true`
4. Run `warble compiled jar`, and you will see your `*.jar` result file.